# I know how to change text using javascript (getElementById), but how do I make that text include eg. links?

Tags: javascript, html

So I know that you can use getElementById to change text inside a webpage.
Something like this for example:

```
document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = "Search engine is here.";
```

But how do I, for example, make the text clickable. I think about something like this, but this won't work obiviously:

```
document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = "<a onclick="myFunction()" href="#">Search engine is here.</a>"
```

So, does anyone have an idea how to do it? Do you need to use jQuery?

Comment: this should work ... probably it's just an error in your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you have a syntax error. This is not related to jQuery. If you need quotes inside a string, you either need to escape the quotes in the string, or change the quotes. You can embed double quotes in single quoted string and vice versa, but to include double quotes in double quoted strings you need to escape them by adding a `\` in front of the quote to escape.

Either one of the three options below will do the trick.

Escaping:

```
document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"myFunction()\" href=\"#\">Search engine is here.</a>";
```

Single quotes in JavaScript, double in HTML:

```
document.getElementById('article').innerHTML = '<a onclick="myFunction()" href="#">Search engine is here.</a>';
```

Double quotes in JavaScript, single in HTML:

```
document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = "<a onclick='myFunction()' href='#'>Search engine is here.</a>";
```

A different approach would by to really construct the element through JavaScript. In this snippet you don't need to escape quotes or mix single and double, although it's still good to know about escaping, since you are inevitably going to need it if you keep doing JavaScript.

Anyway, for educational purposes:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("article");

// Create a link element
var link = document.createElement('a');

// Set its properties, events and content
link.href = '#';
link.onclick = function() {
  alert('clicked!');
}
link.innerText = 'Text content of the link';

// Add the link to the div
div.appendChild(link);
```

```html
<div id="article"></div>
```